# does GraphRbacManagementClient supports Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, azure-sdk-python

Why does GraphRbacManagementClient from azure-sdk-python call to Azure AD Graph API (https://graph.windows.net/) and does not support Microsoft Graph (https://graph.microsoft.com/)?

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/ - "Starting June 30th, 2022, we will end support for and Azure AD Graph and will no longer provide technical support or security updates. Apps using Azure AD Graph after this time will no longer receive responses from the Azure AD Graph endpoint."

So what will happen to this library? There is a plan to refactor?

Comment: Can you explain why you are using the GraphRbacManagementClient or what are you trying to get from Azure AD Graph?

Comment: We are working on a Python library for Microsoft Graph.  We will have something to share later this year.

Comment: Most functionalities in AAD Graph have been supported by Microsoft Graph. Please share what you want to implement with `GraphRbacManagementClient ` so that we could investigate if it can be done with Microsoft Graph.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I'm using it for it's main purpose - to read data from the directory, such as users, groups and apps

Comment: @Allen Wu - same as above

Comment: @DarrelMiller - cool, where the release will be announced?

Comment: @GGeiger  Here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/